# Delete row from table using JQuery. Please see code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a code which I got in the net that adds a table row every onclick event. It worked perfect for me until I realized I needed to have an onclick event for every row that when clicked, it will delete the row.

Is there a way for that to happen using my code?

Please see codes below:

Javascript/JQuery code:

```
<script>
    var counter = 2;            
    function addRow() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><label>'+ counter +'</label></td><td><textarea name="txtActionStep' + counter + '" style="width:300px; height: 50px; word-wrap:break-word;"></textarea></td><td valign="top"><input type="text" name="txtOwner' +              counter + '"/></td></tr>');
        counter++;                
        jQuery('table.actionsteps-list').append( newRow );
    }
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<table class="actionsteps-list" width="510">
   <tr>
       <th colspan="3" align="left">Action Steps</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Step #</td><td>Action Step</td><td>Owner</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label>1</label></td>
       <td><textarea name="txtActionStep1" style="width:300px; height: 50px; word-wrap:break-word;"></textarea></td>
       <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="txtOwner1" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table width="510">
   <tr>
       <td align="right"><a href="#" title="" onclick="javascript:addRow();">Add Action</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a row from a dynamic generate table using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933820/how-to-delete-a-row-from-a-dynamic-generate-table-using-jquery)

Comment: event.preventDefault();, this line will throw script error as event is not defined. Comment out this line and try..

Answer (score 3):

Sure, using delegation we can accomplish that.

```
$('table.actionsteps-list').on('click', 'tr', function(e){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

You probably want to add a button to your row to signal a deletion, so let's assume you add (to each row):

```
<td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
```

Then just change your delegation method like this:

```
$('table.actionsteps-list').on('click', '.delete', function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); // stops the page jumping to the top
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Hello, ahren    

I tried this one but unfortunately all added rows were deleted. I added three rows and when I clicked the delete button for the 2nd one, all three were gone.

Comment: Hi ahren, I guess the reason why it doesn't work for me is because when I clicked the delete button, it submits the form. I tried putting `type=button` inside the button but when I did this, it didn't work anymore. Maybe if I use `<button type="button" onclick="deleteRow">` tag, it will work? But how would my JQuery function for delete row look like?

Comment: @aguas - no need to use inline javascript. See above for the delegated event handler, which has `e.preventDefault()` - this would stop the form from being submitted.

Comment: It's still not working :( even with `e.preventDefault()` the form is submitting whenever I click the delete button. Is there anyway you can check my whole code? Pls help

Comment: @aguas - do you have a live URL then?

Comment: here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8025609/add_reprocessing.php Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if I create the row dynamically?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - this will work if you create the *row* dynamically. However, if you create the *table* dynamically you'd need to bind this handler after it's added to the DOM.

Comment: The table is created using HTML and I just add the row dynamically with an ID for each row. I will test it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a delegate ot catch the event at the table level, that way any new row that you add will also be handled:

```
$('.actionsteps-list').on('click', 'tr', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

---

Side note:

Don't use the `javascript:` protocol for inline Javascript, that's only used when you put Javascript in the `href` attribute of a link:

```
<a href="#" title="" onclick="addRow();">Add Action</a>
```